# Metric Spaces Whose Diameter is Achieved at Every Point.

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space with diameter $\sup \{ d(x,y) \colon  x,y \in X\}=1$.

Call the point $x \in X$ an **edge point** to mean that $d(x,y)=1$ for some $y \in X$.

Call the metric space **round** to mean that every point is an edge point.

Obviously the connected examples that spring to mind are circles and spheres of unit diameter. I wonder are there any other examples?

I tried to construct one in the plane to see what must be done and what can go wrong. So start with two points a unit distance apart. Then everything is within a distance $1$ of $x$ and everything is with a distance $1$ of $y$. That means the space must be contained in the "eye shape."

[image]

But I cannot see any way to restrict further, other than drawing another "eye" between other pairs of points . Only I don't know where those points are allowed to lie in the first place.

The yellow circle is a possible round space containing both points. Are there any others?

Do spaces of this type have another name?

Comment: Would a [Reuleaux Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle) qualify?

Comment: Yes they do, you should add that as an answer.

Comment: There are also Reuleaux tetrahedra. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V5zoWK7KwAc

Comment: Note that this really is highly dependent on the specific metric. Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be any metric space such that there is an $r>0$ such that for each $x\in X$ there is a $y\in X$ with $d(x,y)\ge r$. Then there is an equivalent metric $\rho$ on $X$ such that $\langle X,\rho\rangle$ is round.

Comment: Note that if you talk general metric spaces, this will be true for any space whose group of isometries acts transitively. E. g. any compact Lie group (equipped with invariant metric).

Answer (score 0):

Examples .....

(1) A discrete space with the discrete metric: $d(x,y)=1$ whenever $x\ne y.$

(2) Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle of side length $1.$ Draw a circular arc centered at $A,$ joining $B$ to $C.$ And likewise draw an arc centered at $B,$ from $C$ to $A,$ and an arc centered at $C,$ from $A$ to $B.$  The union of the $3$ arcs is an example.

Comment: Your example 2 is a Reuleaux triangle…

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf . Thanks .I don't always look up all the references in all the comments. And I didn't know this shape had someone's name attached.